# Java - using this

Tags: java

Where would you expect to see the following notation:

```
 this(a,b,0,null)
```

and what would be the effect of evaluating this expression?

Comment: Google for "constructor chaining".

Comment: Comment about downvotes: while the question *does* sound like a copy-paste from homework assignment, I think this is a valid question in itself, and it's quite hard to know what to google, if you do not know what it does.

Comment: It's hard to google, but if you have a homework, you must have had a lesson beforehand, and notes of this lesson or a textbook. And since it's likely one of his first lesson in Java, it's not hard to search the notes about it.

Comment: And since very experienced Java developpers give wrong answers, its valid to ask.

Comment: @AlexWien sure, nitpicking on the terms "overloaded constructor" is gonna help a beginner a lot.

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann - Especially when his nitpicks are technically incorrect.

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann The term overloaded constructor is misleading, especially for a beginner. thats the reason why it is not used when describing alternate constructor calls. Neither by oracle, nor in the JLS.

Answer (score 4):

This can be seen inside an constructor, to call another constructor from the same class. it has to be  the first line in the constructor.
This is a so called *alternate constructor invocation*.

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1)

> Alternate constructor invocations begin with the keyword this
>   (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments). They are used to
>   invoke an alternate constructor of the same class.
>    An explicit
>   constructor invocation statement in a constructor body may not refer
>   to any instance variables or instance methods or inner classes
>   declared in this class or any superclass, or use this or super in any
>   expression; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

That expression would be legal as the first line inside a constructor. It's effect would be to invoke an overloaded constructor with different arguments.

Comment: Are you sure that the term "overloaded constructor" is coreect here?

Comment: @AlexWien - That's consistent with the terminology used in the [Java Language Specification §8.8.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.8): _"Overloading of constructors is identical in behavior to overloading of methods"_

Comment: i cited the JLS, in my answer they do not call it over loaded constructor, are they?

Comment: @AlexWien - In the next section after what you cited, they use the phrase "overloading of constructors". That makes perfectly clear that constructors can be overloaded and seems to legitimize my terminology.

Comment: You are wrong, it has not nessessarily to be an overloaded constructor, it can be any constructor from the same class. The overladed constructor, is the next chapter in the JLS (8.8.8), and is not related to alternative constructor invocation.

Comment: @AlexWien - You are wrong. Recursive constructor invocation is illegal. A constructor must invoke an alternative constructor (that is, an overloaded constructor with different arguments, since it cannot invoke the constructor that is executing). If you try to recursively invoke a constructor from within itself, the compiler will complain.

Comment: i must correct, it can be any of the other constructors of the same class, but not neccessarily an overloaded one. This is simply wrong. neither the oracle tutorial, nor the JLS refers to overloaded constructors, when describing the alternate constructor invocation

Comment: @AlexWien - Please explain how you can you have an "other constructor" without having an overloaded constructor. From §8.4.9: _"If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded."_ Section 8.8.8 says that the identical rule applies to constructors.

Comment: The point is that the term "overloaded constructor" includes constructoes from the super class, but these cannot be invoked via this(). it would be correct when you write "overloaded constructors from the same class".

Comment: @AlexWien - "overloaded constructor" does not include constructors from the super class because constructors are not inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Using `this()` is to call the constructor from within a class; from within that class' constructor.